# SQL query distinct not working

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
        DECLARE @Region VARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @Region = ''
        SELECT @Region = @Region + BillState + N',' FROM Distributor WHERE BillCountry = 'US' AND BillState != ''
        PRINT @Region
```

Which returns the following string:

```
NY,UT,NV,UT,UT,UT,UT,NV,CA,UT,UT,UT,SD,NV,UT,UT,NV,NV,SD,UT,SD,SD,UT,SD,AZ,SD,SD,SD,UT,TX,ID,UT,UT,UT,CO,SC,UT,UT,UT,SD,CA,UT,UT,UT,UT,SD,UT,NV,NV,WA,NV,NV,UT,CA,UT,NV,UT,UT,ID,CA,UT,SD,UT,UT,SC,UT,UT,UT,WA,SD,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,SD,SD,UT,UT,UT,UT,CA,CA,UT,UT,CA,UT,SC,UT,CA,UT,CA,UT,CA,UT,UT,PA,UT,CA,UT,AZ,UT,UT,CA,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,ND,NY,NV,UT,SD,UT,UT,UT,NV,UT,UT,UT,UT,SD,UT,UT,UT,SD,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,NY,SD,UT,UT,TX,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,AL,UT,FL,UT,TX,UT,UT,UT,MI,CO,UT,UT,NY,TX,TX,TX,TX,TX,TX,TX,tx,TX,TX,tx,TX,CA,UT,TX,Co,TX,TX,UT,UT,AR,AR,AR,AR,AR,AR,AR,UT,TX,UT,TX,AR,AR,AR,TX,UT,TX,AZ,UT,UT,UT,UT,OK,TX,OK,OK,OK,WY,UT,UT,TX,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,CA,TX,UT,TX,CA,NY,NY,NY,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,IL,ut,ID,UT,SD,UT,UT,UT,UT,TX,UT,TX,TX,UT,UT,UT,UT,NE,NE,NY,NE,PA,WI,UT,NE,TX,AZ,TX,CA,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,CO,WY,UT,CT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,TX,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,TX,UT,UT,NY,UT,UT,UT,GA,UT,NV,TX,NE,UT,NY,CA,IA,CA,TX,UT,UT,ID,UT,MO,UT,UT,CT,UT,GA,MO,AZ,TN,MO,NV,GA,CA,UT,AR,MN,MN,GA,AR,MS,CA,MO,CA,MO,GA,UT,NC,UT,UT,MO,UT,GA,MO,MO,AR,GA,UT,NC,UT,UT,UT,OK,TN,MO,MI,GA,MS,GA,CA,MO,GA,MO,MO,NY,GA,GA,SC,PA,GA,CA,WI,GA,GA,GA,GA,UT,CO,GA,FL,NJ,TN,GA,TX,OK,AR,GA,GA,AR,UT,AR,AR,MO,VA,GA,GA,TX,MO,MO,GA,GA,GA,MO,MO,HI,GA,MO,IL,AR,AR,AR,MO,OK,MO,GA,AR,MO,AR,OK,MO,IL,CA,NE,UT,GA,GA,GA,ga,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,TX,GA,TX,MO,GA,UT,GA,MO,MO,MO,MO,TX,GA,MO,MO,GA,AR,SC,GA,UT,GA,UT,GA,IL,CA,FL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MT,GA,NY,UT,AL,NE,MD,AL,GA,ME,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,AL,UT,GA,TN,FL,AL,GA,FL,AL,GA,GA,TN,GA,AL,GA,WA,TX,GA,GA,FL,TX,UT,GA,GA,NC,NC,MT,MT,MT,GA,MS,GA,MO,GA,TN,GA,ID,UT,MO,GA,OR,GA,NC,ME,GA,GA,FL,UT,MO,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,GA,OR,GA,OR,GA,UT,UT,TX,GA,GA,SC,SC,AL,IL,SC,AL,GA,UT,OR,GA,AL,GA,GA,SC,GA,GA,GA,FL,TN,GA,AL,GA,GA,AR,AR,UT,UT,UT,GA,AL,GA,UT,FL,GA,UT,GA,UT,UT,CA,MS,UT,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,UT,MS,GA,GA,MS,GA,GA,MS,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,UT,UT,UT,UT,GA,GA,UT,MO,GA,GA,GA,NE,GA,GA,GA,GA,SC,GA,GA,TN,UT,GA,GA,GA,NY,GA,GA,GA,MO,GA,GA,UT,MN,UT,CA,MS,GA,WA,UT,GA,WA,AL,MO,NC,GA,NC,TN,CA,GA,TX,TX,TX,FL,GA,MO,GA,GA,GA,WA,GA,GA,GA,MS,OR,GA,GA,TX,GA,WY,GA,GA,SC,OR,AL,GA,AL,GA,UT,FL,AL,AL,GA,GA,GA,TN,OR,OH,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,SC,GA,GA,GA,GA,FL,GA,GA,FL,AL,GA,IN,GA,SC,IL,FL,AL,MS,MS,WI,GA,MD,MO,NC,MO,TN,NC,TN,TN,WA,GA,GA,TN,MO,GA,GA,GA,AL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,AL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,VA,AL,GA,MO,GA,OR,GA,GA,AL,GA,GA,GA,AL,GA,GA,GA,GA,FL,NC,TX,TX,GA,TX,GA,TX,TN,tX,tx,TX,tx,TN,FL,TX,TX,GA,AK,TX,TX,TX,GA,TN,TX,GA,SC,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,WI,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,OH,GA,FL,GA,GA,GA,UT,OR,NC,GA,GA,GA,GA,WA,SD,GA,WA,GA,GA,GA,GA,AL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,OK,AL,GA,GA,MD,AZ,KY,GA,GA,OK,OR,GA,GA,FL,NY,CA,GA,AZ,TX,GA,MS,MS,NY,GA,FL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,TX,GA,GA,GA,GA,AK,GA,OR,GA,MS,GA,GA,MI,GA,OR,GA,OR,AL,NC,GA,OR,SC,MI,GA,MI,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MI,KY,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,UT,FL,MS,GA,SC,TN,GA,GA,TN,GA,GA,GA,GA,MN,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,TN,AL,MI,IN,GA,GA,GA,MI,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MI,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MI,GA,MN,GA,GA,GA,MN,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MN,OR,WA,MS,FL,MI,MI,GA,FL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,NC,GA,MI,GA,ID,GA,GA,MI,GA,GA,GA,GA,TX,GA,GA,SC,GA,GA,MI,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,CA,GA,GA,GA,UT,WI,GA,GA,GA,OK,NC,NV,UT,MO,GA,AK,GA,OH,VA,GA,FL,GA,UT,UT,UT,GA,UT,GA,GA,AZ,GA,GA,Ga,GA,GA,GA,TN,GA,GA,SC,GA,MO,OR,OR,GA,UT,GA,MI,GA,SC,GA,SC,MO,AZ,MS,GA,MS,MS,MS,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,UT,GA,GA,UT,GA,UT,UT,GA,GA,GA,TX,MN,GA,TX,MS,GA,GA,NY,OH,CO,CO,GA,MD,GA,GA,CO,GA,GA,MS,GA,MS,MN,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,TX,GA,CT,MS,GA,GA,ga,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MS,UT,AL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MS,GA,MS,GA,GA,GA,TN,GA,GA,GA,WI,GA,MI,AL,FL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,AL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MS,GA,GA,FL,GA,GA,GA,GA,UT,GA,GA,GA,CA,FL,GA,TX,MN,GA,GA,TX,GA,GA,WV,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MS,MS,MS,NC,MS,FL,TX,SC,GA,GA,GA,MS,GA,GA,AL,TN,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,AZ,GA,GA,NY,ut,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MS,MS,GA,GA,GA,OK,FL,MS,GA,GA,AR,GA,al,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,AL,VI,AR,AK,AR,TX,FL,GA,GA,IA,MS,GA,GA,GA,GA,SC,GA,MS,GA,UT,TN,GA,OR,TN,GA,GA,GA,NC,SC,GA,GA,FL,FL,GA,AL,GA,NC,FL,GA,GA,GA,NY,TN,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,MO,GA,AZ,GA,GA,GA,NV,UT,MO,SC,GA,GA,GA,GA,OR,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MS,AZ,PA,GA,GA,TN,UT,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,NY,GA,FL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,TX,GA,TX,GA,TX,GA,GA,AL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,OR,GA,GA,MS,MS,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MS,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,TX,GA,GA,TN,GA,AK,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,AL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MS,MS,GA,UT,UT,WA,TN,GA,GA,GA,TN,GA,GA,VA,GA,GA,NH,GA,CA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,IA,MS,UT,GA,GA,FL,OH,AL,CO,GA,GA,MS,GA,GA,GA,CT,GA,GA,GA,VA,GA,MO,GA,GA,GA,GA,MS,GA,GA,GA,GA,RI,GA,GA,GA,CA,GA,MO,GA,GA,GA,OR,FL,NY,MS,GA,TX,SC,GA,WA,GA,GA,CA,UT,MO,GA,GA,NV,GA,GA,GA,GA,FL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,ID,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,GA,GA,MO,MO,NY,GA,GA,SD,GA,GA,GA,GA,FL,GA,GA,GA,MO,GA,MO,MO,GA,MO,MO,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MS,GA,GA,GA,TX,MO,FL,GA,MO,TN,UT,GA,GA,MO,MO,TX,MO,GA,NC,GA,GA,TN,GA,MO,GA,SC,GA,GA,OK,GA,GA,MS,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,GA,GA,GA,GA,FL,GA,FL,MO,MO,MO,FL,GA,GA,MO,MO,MO,TN,GA,GA,MO,MO,GA,GA,OR,GA,FL,GA,GA,NV,NV,GA,GA,NV,CA,LA,TX,GA,GA,AL,GA,GA,UT,GA,GA,AL,MD,GA,GA,MO,GA,MS,MS,CA,TX,TX,TX,CA,GA,GA,GA,IL,TX,TX,MS,LA,TX,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,FL,GA,GA,CA,LA,GA,GA,AL,GA,GA,FL,GA,GA,TN,GA,PA,TN,GA,GA,GA,GA,WI,NC,GA,LA,MO,SC,IL,MO,TX,MD,GA,OH,CA,GA,GA,GA,GA,AL,GA,CA,MO,GA,CT,FL,GA,FL,FL,NC,GA,CO,GA,GA,FL,MO,AL,GA,AL,AL,AL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,WA,OH,MO,GA,GA,GA,GA,AL,GA,CO,ME,OH,GA,FL,NC,GA,MO,MO,GA,GA,MS,MS,MS,MS,NC,FL,MN,AL,GA,AK,GA,GA,GA,IN,GA,CO,ID,MO,MO,GA,TN,GA,GA,NH,ME,GA,GA,IL,GA,GA,GA,GA,AK,MO,FL,MO,MO,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,FL,UT,TX,NM,GA,GA,FL,WI,MO,GA,GA,FL,SC,KY,GA,IL,GA,MT,MO,GA,MO,GA,GA,GA,GA,WA,WI,MO,GA,NC,GA,MO,MO,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,GA,GA,MS,GA,IN,FL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,GA,FL,GA,FL,FL,MO,GA,GA,AL,GA,Id,MS,GA,GA,GA,MO,UT,GA,GA,FL,PA,OR,GA,GA,GA,FL,GA,GA,FL,SC,GA,GA,VA,PA,GA,GA,TX,GA,GA,GA,IA,GA,SC,GA,GA,GA,MO,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,AZ,GA,MO,GA,MO,GA,GA,IN,NE,AZ,KY,AZ,VA,OR,MO,GA,AZ,ME,GA,GA,FL,MO,GA,GA,GA,MO,KS,GA,MO,FL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,WI,GA,MO,GA,GA,TN,UT,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,GA,GA,FL,FL,IL,GA,NC,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,FL,GA,WI,GA,TN,CA,GA,NY,FL,GA,MI,FL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MS,MS,MS,GA,MO,GA,GA,IL,GA,UT,TX,GA,GA,TN,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,ID,AR,AL,MA,UT,GA,GA,MO,GA,GA,GA,TN,AL,GA,GA,GA,GA,FL,GA,GA,GA,FL,TX,FL,MO,GA,GA,GA,GA,FL,GA,GA,TN,GA,WY,IA,GA,SC,OK,GA,GA,GA,GA,WY,GA,GA,NY,GA,WY,MO,CA,GA,MO,GA,WA,MO,NC,GA,GA,GA,FL,FL,GA,IN,GA,FL,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,FL,GA,GA,AL,FL,WI,OH,IN,IN,GA,WI,IN,GA,GA,IN,WI,FL,GA,GA,MD,MO,FL,GA,PA,OR,GA,MO,IN,GA,GA,GA,MD,GA,AZ,OR,MO,FL,GA,GA,FL,MO,GA,FL,GA,FL,FL,FL,GA,GA,TX,TX,GA,GA,NY,NY,AZ,NY,OR,OH,MO,GA,GA,MS,GA,GA,VA,MO,MO,GA,MO,IN,OH,GA,GA,GA,MT,MS,GA,GA,TX,GA,CA,GA,GA,GA,GA,TX,MS,GA,MO,MT,MT,MO,FL,GA,MT,GA,MT,FL,MT,OR,GA,GA,WI,MO,GA,MO,TX,GA,MI,GA,GA,GA,MT,GA,GA,FL,AR,GA,GA,MO,FL,OK,GA,MO,OK,TX,IL,MO,TX,NY,IN,GA,TX,GA,MO,GA,OK,GA,GA,WI,MO,MO,IN,AL,IN,IN,TX,GA,GA,IN,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,FL,FL,NY,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MT,NC,GA,GA,OR,GA,MO,GA,GA,GA,GA,MO,MO,FL,OH,GA,NC,AL,GA,TN,CA,GA,MO,GA,FL,FL,GA,GA,FL,MI,FL,MO,MO,GA,GA,MO,MO,MO,MO,FL,AL,FL,FL,GA,FL,GA,TN,FL,FL,GA,MO,GA,FL,GA,GA,GA,FL,GA,GA,AL,GA,FL,GA,GA,MT,GA,MT,TX,WV,NC,GA,CA,GA,FL,GA,GA,FL,TX,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,GA,MT,MO,MT,FL,GA,FL,GA,GA,GA,FL,SC,OH,GA,FL,FL,GA,GA,OH,GA,GA,FL,WI,NY,OH,MT,MT,OH,GA,GA,GA
```

Here is the data that is pulled and turned into the string above:

```
NY
UT
NV
UT
UT
UT
UT
NV
CA
UT
UT
UT
SD
NV
UT
UT
NV
NV
SD
UT
SD
SD
UT
SD
AZ
SD
SD
SD
UT
TX
ID
UT
UT
UT
CO
SC
UT
UT
UT
SD
CA
UT
UT
UT
UT
SD
UT
NV
NV
WA
NV
NV
UT
CA
UT
NV
UT
UT
ID
CA
UT
SD
UT
UT
SC
UT
UT
UT
WA
SD
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
SD
SD
UT
UT
UT
UT
CA
CA
UT
UT
CA
UT
SC
UT
CA
UT
CA
UT
CA
UT
UT
PA
UT
CA
UT
AZ
UT
UT
CA
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
ND
NY
NV
UT
SD
UT
UT
UT
NV
UT
UT
UT
UT
SD
UT
UT
UT
SD
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
NY
SD
UT
UT
TX
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
AL
UT
FL
UT
TX
UT
UT
UT
MI
CO
UT
UT
NY
TX
TX
TX
TX
TX
TX
TX
tx
TX
TX
tx
TX
CA
UT
TX
Co
TX
TX
UT
UT
AR
AR
AR
AR
AR
AR
AR
UT
TX
UT
TX
AR
AR
AR
TX
UT
TX
AZ
UT
UT
UT
UT
OK
TX
OK
OK
OK
WY
UT
UT
TX
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
CA
TX
UT
TX
CA
NY
NY
NY
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
IL
ut
ID
UT
SD
UT
UT
UT
UT
TX
UT
TX
TX
UT
UT
UT
UT
NE
NE
NY
NE
PA
WI
UT
NE
TX
AZ
TX
CA
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
CO
WY
UT
CT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
TX
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
TX
UT
UT
NY
UT
UT
UT
GA
UT
NV
TX
NE
UT
NY
CA
IA
CA
TX
UT
UT
ID
UT
MO
UT
UT
CT
UT
GA
MO
AZ
TN
MO
NV
GA
CA
UT
AR
MN
MN
GA
AR
MS
CA
MO
CA
MO
GA
UT
NC
UT
UT
MO
UT
GA
MO
MO
AR
GA
UT
NC
UT
UT
UT
OK
TN
MO
MI
GA
MS
GA
CA
MO
GA
MO
MO
NY
GA
GA
SC
PA
GA
CA
WI
GA
GA
GA
GA
UT
CO
GA
FL
NJ
TN
GA
TX
OK
AR
GA
GA
AR
UT
AR
AR
MO
VA
GA
GA
TX
MO
MO
GA
GA
GA
MO
MO
HI
GA
MO
IL
AR
AR
AR
MO
OK
MO
GA
AR
MO
AR
OK
MO
IL
CA
NE
UT
GA
GA
GA
ga
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
TX
GA
TX
MO
GA
UT
GA
MO
MO
MO
MO
TX
GA
MO
MO
GA
AR
SC
GA
UT
GA
UT
GA
IL
CA
FL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MT
GA
NY
UT
AL
NE
MD
AL
GA
ME
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
AL
UT
GA
TN
FL
AL
GA
FL
AL
GA
GA
TN
GA
AL
GA
WA
TX
GA
GA
FL
TX
UT
GA
GA
NC
NC
MT
MT
MT
GA
MS
GA
MO
GA
TN
GA
ID
UT
MO
GA
OR
GA
NC
ME
GA
GA
FL
UT
MO
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
GA
OR
GA
OR
GA
UT
UT
TX
GA
GA
SC
SC
AL
IL
SC
AL
GA
UT
OR
GA
AL
GA
GA
SC
GA
GA
GA
FL
TN
GA
AL
GA
GA
AR
AR
UT
UT
UT
GA
AL
GA
UT
FL
GA
UT
GA
UT
UT
CA
MS
UT
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
UT
MS
GA
GA
MS
GA
GA
MS
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
UT
UT
UT
UT
GA
GA
UT
MO
GA
GA
GA
NE
GA
GA
GA
GA
SC
GA
GA
TN
UT
GA
GA
GA
NY
GA
GA
GA
MO
GA
GA
UT
MN
UT
CA
MS
GA
WA
UT
GA
WA
AL
MO
NC
GA
NC
TN
CA
GA
TX
TX
TX
FL
GA
MO
GA
GA
GA
WA
GA
GA
GA
MS
OR
GA
GA
TX
GA
WY
GA
GA
SC
OR
AL
GA
AL
GA
UT
FL
AL
AL
GA
GA
GA
TN
OR
OH
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
SC
GA
GA
GA
GA
FL
GA
GA
FL
AL
GA
IN
GA
SC
IL
FL
AL
MS
MS
WI
GA
MD
MO
NC
MO
TN
NC
TN
TN
WA
GA
GA
TN
MO
GA
GA
GA
AL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
AL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
VA
AL
GA
MO
GA
OR
GA
GA
AL
GA
GA
GA
AL
GA
GA
GA
GA
FL
NC
TX
TX
GA
TX
GA
TX
TN
tX
tx
TX
tx
TN
FL
TX
TX
GA
AK
TX
TX
TX
GA
TN
TX
GA
SC
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
WI
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
OH
GA
FL
GA
GA
GA
UT
OR
NC
GA
GA
GA
GA
WA
SD
GA
WA
GA
GA
GA
GA
AL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
OK
AL
GA
GA
MD
AZ
KY
GA
GA
OK
OR
GA
GA
FL
NY
CA
GA
AZ
TX
GA
MS
MS
NY
GA
FL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
TX
GA
GA
GA
GA
AK
GA
OR
GA
MS
GA
GA
MI
GA
OR
GA
OR
AL
NC
GA
OR
SC
MI
GA
MI
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MI
KY
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
UT
FL
MS
GA
SC
TN
GA
GA
TN
GA
GA
GA
GA
MN
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
TN
AL
MI
IN
GA
GA
GA
MI
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MI
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MI
GA
MN
GA
GA
GA
MN
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MN
OR
WA
MS
FL
MI
MI
GA
FL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
NC
GA
MI
GA
ID
GA
GA
MI
GA
GA
GA
GA
TX
GA
GA
SC
GA
GA
MI
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
CA
GA
GA
GA
UT
WI
GA
GA
GA
OK
NC
NV
UT
MO
GA
AK
GA
OH
VA
GA
FL
GA
UT
UT
UT
GA
UT
GA
GA
AZ
GA
GA
Ga
GA
GA
GA
TN
GA
GA
SC
GA
MO
OR
OR
GA
UT
GA
MI
GA
SC
GA
SC
MO
AZ
MS
GA
MS
MS
MS
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
UT
GA
GA
UT
GA
UT
UT
GA
GA
GA
TX
MN
GA
TX
MS
GA
GA
NY
OH
CO
CO
GA
MD
GA
GA
CO
GA
GA
MS
GA
MS
MN
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
TX
GA
CT
MS
GA
GA
ga
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MS
UT
AL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MS
GA
MS
GA
GA
GA
TN
GA
GA
GA
WI
GA
MI
AL
FL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
AL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MS
GA
GA
FL
GA
GA
GA
GA
UT
GA
GA
GA
CA
FL
GA
TX
MN
GA
GA
TX
GA
GA
WV
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MS
MS
MS
NC
MS
FL
TX
SC
GA
GA
GA
MS
GA
GA
AL
TN
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
AZ
GA
GA
NY
ut
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MS
MS
GA
GA
GA
OK
FL
MS
GA
GA
AR
GA
al
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
AL
VI
AR
AK
AR
TX
FL
GA
GA
IA
MS
GA
GA
GA
GA
SC
GA
MS
GA
UT
TN
GA
OR
TN
GA
GA
GA
NC
SC
GA
GA
FL
FL
GA
AL
GA
NC
FL
GA
GA
GA
NY
TN
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
MO
GA
AZ
GA
GA
GA
NV
UT
MO
SC
GA
GA
GA
GA
OR
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MS
AZ
PA
GA
GA
TN
UT
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
NY
GA
FL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
TX
GA
TX
GA
TX
GA
GA
AL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
OR
GA
GA
MS
MS
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MS
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
TX
GA
GA
TN
GA
AK
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
AL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MS
MS
GA
UT
UT
WA
TN
GA
GA
GA
TN
GA
GA
VA
GA
GA
NH
GA
CA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
IA
MS
UT
GA
GA
FL
OH
AL
CO
GA
GA
MS
GA
GA
GA
CT
GA
GA
GA
VA
GA
MO
GA
GA
GA
GA
MS
GA
GA
GA
GA
RI
GA
GA
GA
CA
GA
MO
GA
GA
GA
OR
FL
NY
MS
GA
TX
SC
GA
WA
GA
GA
CA
UT
MO
GA
GA
NV
GA
GA
GA
GA
FL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
ID
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
GA
GA
MO
MO
NY
GA
GA
SD
GA
GA
GA
GA
FL
GA
GA
GA
MO
GA
MO
MO
GA
MO
MO
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MS
GA
GA
GA
TX
MO
FL
GA
MO
TN
UT
GA
GA
MO
MO
TX
MO
GA
NC
GA
GA
TN
GA
MO
GA
SC
GA
GA
OK
GA
GA
MS
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
GA
GA
GA
GA
FL
GA
FL
MO
MO
MO
FL
GA
GA
MO
MO
MO
TN
GA
GA
MO
MO
GA
GA
OR
GA
FL
GA
GA
NV
NV
GA
GA
NV
CA
LA
TX
GA
GA
AL
GA
GA
UT
GA
GA
AL
MD
GA
GA
MO
GA
MS
MS
CA
TX
TX
TX
CA
GA
GA
GA
IL
TX
TX
MS
LA
TX
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
FL
GA
GA
CA
LA
GA
GA
AL
GA
GA
FL
GA
GA
TN
GA
PA
TN
GA
GA
GA
GA
WI
NC
GA
LA
MO
SC
IL
MO
TX
MD
GA
OH
CA
GA
GA
GA
GA
AL
GA
CA
MO
GA
CT
FL
GA
FL
FL
NC
GA
CO
GA
GA
FL
MO
AL
GA
AL
AL
AL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
WA
OH
MO
GA
GA
GA
GA
AL
GA
CO
ME
OH
GA
FL
NC
GA
MO
MO
GA
GA
MS
MS
MS
MS
NC
FL
MN
AL
GA
AK
GA
GA
GA
IN
GA
CO
ID
MO
MO
GA
TN
GA
GA
NH
ME
GA
GA
IL
GA
GA
GA
GA
AK
MO
FL
MO
MO
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
FL
UT
TX
NM
GA
GA
FL
WI
MO
GA
GA
FL
SC
KY
GA
IL
GA
MT
MO
GA
MO
GA
GA
GA
GA
WA
WI
MO
GA
NC
GA
MO
MO
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
GA
GA
MS
GA
IN
FL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
GA
FL
GA
FL
FL
MO
GA
GA
AL
GA
Id
MS
GA
GA
GA
MO
UT
GA
GA
FL
PA
OR
GA
GA
GA
FL
GA
GA
FL
SC
GA
GA
VA
PA
GA
GA
TX
GA
GA
GA
IA
GA
SC
GA
GA
GA
MO
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
AZ
GA
MO
GA
MO
GA
GA
IN
NE
AZ
KY
AZ
VA
OR
MO
GA
AZ
ME
GA
GA
FL
MO
GA
GA
GA
MO
KS
GA
MO
FL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
WI
GA
MO
GA
GA
TN
UT
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
GA
GA
FL
FL
IL
GA
NC
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
FL
GA
WI
GA
TN
CA
GA
NY
FL
GA
MI
FL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MS
MS
MS
GA
MO
GA
GA
IL
GA
UT
TX
GA
GA
TN
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
ID
AR
AL
MA
UT
GA
GA
MO
GA
GA
GA
TN
AL
GA
GA
GA
GA
FL
GA
GA
GA
FL
TX
FL
MO
GA
GA
GA
GA
FL
GA
GA
TN
GA
WY
IA
GA
SC
OK
GA
GA
GA
GA
WY
GA
GA
NY
GA
WY
MO
CA
GA
MO
GA
WA
MO
NC
GA
GA
GA
FL
FL
GA
IN
GA
FL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
FL
GA
GA
AL
FL
WI
OH
IN
IN
GA
WI
IN
GA
GA
IN
WI
FL
GA
GA
MD
MO
FL
GA
PA
OR
GA
MO
IN
GA
GA
GA
MD
GA
AZ
OR
MO
FL
GA
GA
FL
MO
GA
FL
GA
FL
FL
FL
GA
GA
TX
TX
GA
GA
NY
NY
AZ
NY
OR
OH
MO
GA
GA
MS
GA
GA
VA
MO
MO
GA
MO
IN
OH
GA
GA
GA
MT
MS
GA
GA
TX
GA
CA
GA
GA
GA
GA
TX
MS
GA
MO
MT
MT
MO
FL
GA
MT
GA
MT
FL
MT
OR
GA
GA
WI
MO
GA
MO
TX
GA
MI
GA
GA
GA
MT
GA
GA
FL
AR
GA
GA
MO
FL
OK
GA
MO
OK
TX
IL
MO
TX
NY
IN
GA
TX
GA
MO
GA
OK
GA
GA
WI
MO
MO
IN
AL
IN
IN
TX
GA
GA
IN
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
FL
FL
NY
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MT
NC
GA
GA
OR
GA
MO
GA
GA
GA
GA
MO
MO
FL
OH
GA
NC
AL
GA
TN
CA
GA
MO
GA
FL
FL
GA
GA
FL
MI
FL
MO
MO
GA
GA
MO
MO
MO
MO
FL
AL
FL
FL
GA
FL
GA
TN
FL
FL
GA
MO
GA
FL
GA
GA
GA
FL
GA
GA
AL
GA
FL
GA
GA
MT
GA
MT
TX
WV
NC
GA
CA
GA
FL
GA
GA
FL
TX
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
MT
MO
MT
FL
GA
FL
GA
GA
GA
FL
SC
OH
GA
FL
FL
GA
GA
OH
GA
GA
FL
WI
NY
OH
MT
MT
OH
GA
GA
GA
OH
MT
OH
OH
MT
MT
OH
FL
FL
FL
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
IN
FL
FL
CA
NJ
GA
GA
FL
UT
FL
CA
WI
CO
IN
FL
IN
NC
AK
NC
IL
OH
FL
WI
OH
CO
GA
GA
MO
NC
FL
GA
FL
GA
GA
GA
FL
GA
MT
FL
TN
FL
FL
FL
FL
FL
FL
FL
GA
CA
FL
GA
GA
TN
PA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
GA
PA
GA
NJ
GA
TX
MT
NC
FL
FL
UT
FL
GA
NC
AR
FL
FL
GA
GA
PA
GA
CO
GA
FL
GA
TX
FL
FL
PA
AZ
OH
GA
NC
CO
AR
PA
NE
LA
IL
CA
GA
GA
OH
OH
OH
CO
GA
HI
HI
MO
FL
OH
AZ
GA
FL
FM
FL
MO
IL
FL
CO
GA
FL
GA
FL
FL
IL
GA
FL
NJ
FL
GA
GA
GA
CO
AZ
NC
GA
AZ
TX
GA
GA
MO
AL
CO
NY
OH
UT
GA
MO
NM
GA
GA
FL
GA
PA
OH
PA
TN
GA
UT
GA
FL
Tx
AK
NC
NY
GA
FL
OH
OH
FL
FL
GA
GA
GA
FL
```

I am trying to get the distinct values for the statecode.  But distinct doesn't seem to work, it will only return one value which is `wy,`

Any idea what i am missing?  I remove some data as i more than reached the max body count side.

Comment: Your query doesn't *use* DISTINCT...

Comment: I know that, I posted in the question that DISTINCT was not working.  Which it isn't.

Comment: It's traditional to show what you've tried which isn't working... otherwise we can't tell what you've done wrong.

Comment: [The correct behavior for an aggregate concatenation query is undefined.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515/en-us). Use `XML PATH` to concatenate the strings without it unexpectedly breaking when the compute scalar happens to end up on the wrong side of the sort.

Comment: We can't know how DISTINCT is not working if you don't post how you are using it.

Comment: @Blam "I am trying to get the distinct values for the statecode. But distinct doesn't seem to work, it will only return one value which is wy," if I was using it incorrectly it would have given an error.  The only way to use distinct to my knowledge is 'SELECT DISTINCT'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try GROUP BY ?

```
    DECLARE @Region VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Region = ''
    SELECT @Region = @Region + BillState + N',' FROM Distributor WHERE BillCountry = 'US' AND BillState != '' GROUP BY BillState
    PRINT @Region
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `distinct` inside a nested query, like this:

```
SELECT
    @Region = @Region + BillState + N','
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT -- <<--- HERE
        Billstate
    FROM Distributor
    WHERE
        BillCountry = 'US' AND BillState != ''
     ) inner
```